# How to avoid raising exception when nested attributes failed to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`Parent` has many `children` and I want to (bulk) insert children with using `parent.update(children: children)`, like this

```rb
parent = Parent.find(id)
if parent.update(children: children)
    # render OK
else
    # render Error
end
```

`Child` is validated by `validates_uniqueness_of :parent_id, scope: :number` and it also has constraint `UNIQUE (parent_id, number)`.

I want `parent.update(children: children)` to return `false` when the `children` have some duplicated keys. But it raises exception of `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved`, and `parent` has `errors` field with `Couldn't save Parent`.

I'm, regretfully, using `begin rescue` for catch this error.

Is there any way to avoid raising exception, and let `parent.update` return `false` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like in this situation you want to wrap the parent.update in a transaction so that if any of the child records fails validation, the entire transaction will be rolled back. You will still end up handling an exception

```
parent = Parent.find(id)
parent.transaction do
   begin
     parent.update(children: children)
     # render OK
   rescue
     # render Error
   end
end
```

If it's important that you end up with a value of `false` you can put the update transaction in its own function and return true or false

```
def update_children(parent, children)
  parent.transaction do
  begin
    parent.update(children: children)
  rescue
    false
  end
end
```

and decide what to render based on that result:

```
parent = Parent.find(id)
if update_children(parent, children)
  # render OK
else
  # render Error
end
```